# Using partial template specialization to select base class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm new to some of the advanced template techniques I'm trying to use below, so I suspect my terminology may not be quite correct. I have a `Box` base type and several classes that inherit from `Box`. I'm trying to construct an instance of a particular sub-class based on template parameters.

This is the `Box<T>` type. The `Convert` function can create a new `Box<U>` using a function that returns type U.

```
template<typename T>
class Box : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Box<T>> {
 public:

  // Box<T> --> Box<U>
  template <typename Func>
  auto Convert(Func f) -> std::shared_ptr<Box<decltype(f(std::declval<T>()))>>;

  virtual void Print() {
    std::cout << "box" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

I can create a new `Box<int>` type like so:

`auto box = std::shared_ptr<Box<int>>(new Box<int>());`

To convert to another type, we return a sub-class of type `ConvertedBox` (in practice we do this because we are applying the function lazily).

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename Func>
class ConvertedBox : public Box<T> {
 public:
  ConvertedBox(typename std::shared_ptr<Box<U>> box, Func func) :
    box_(box), func_(func)
  {}

  virtual void Print() {
    std::cout << "converted box" << std::endl;
  }

 private:
  std::shared_ptr<Box<U>> box_;
  Func func_;
};
```

And method here to construct the sub-class instance.

```
// implementation of convert
template <typename T>
template <typename Func>
auto Box<T>::Convert(Func f) -> std::shared_ptr<Box<decltype(f(std::declval<T>()))>>
{
    using ReturnType = decltype(f(std::declval<T>()));
    auto p = new ConvertedBox<ReturnType, T, Func>(this->shared_from_this(), f);
    return std::shared_ptr<Box<ReturnType>>(p);
}
```

Now I can construct a new `Box<U>` using a call such as:

```
auto converted_float_box = box->Convert([](int v) -> float {
  return (float)v;
});
```

What I want to be able to do is specialize the `Box<>` base class depending on the type of function being applied. For instance, if I convert to `Box<std::pair<int, int>>` like so:

```
auto converted_pair_box = box->Convert([](int v) -> std::pair<int, int> {
  return std::make_pair(v, v);
});
```

I'd like to be able to call a function on the result that is only available to `Box<std::pair<K, V>>` (I'm using print here as an example. In practice the specializations are complex).

```
converted_pair_box->PairOnlyPrint();
```

I've tried to specialize `Box` on the `std::pair<K,V>`, but with no luck.

```
template<typename K, typename V>
class PairBox : public Box<std::pair<K, V>> {
 public:
  void PairOnlyPrint() {
    std::cout << "only pair box" << std::endl;
  };
};
```

The compiler is still resolving to `Box<>` so the `PairOnlyPrint` isn't available. Is there a method for achieving this?

Edit 1: as pointed out, `Convert` is not a free function.

Comment: `Convert` returns a `Box<T>`, so what you get is a `Box<T>` not a `PairBox`. What you could do is pass the derived class as a template argument to the base class (`Box<T, Derived>`). Although this assumes `Convert` isn't really a free function (it isn't in the example).

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that I knew that was an issue. In general I got stuck at this point trying to what feels like a 'if' statement in the `Convert` function. What you are suggesting is CRTP?

Comment: yes, the suggestion would make use of CRTP.  You could also add the template parameter to `Convert` though.

Answer (score 1):

Your `class PairBox` is not a specialization, a specialization would be:

```
template<typename K, typename V>
class Box<std::pair<K, V>>: public std::enable_shared_from_this<Box<std::pair<K, V>>> {
 public:

  // Box<T> --> Box<U>
  template <typename Func>
  auto Convert(Func f)
  -> std::shared_ptr<Box<decltype(f(std::declval<std::pair<K, V>>()))>>;

  virtual void Print() { std::cout << "pair box" << std::endl; }
  void PairOnlyPrint() { std::cout << "only pair box" << std::endl; };
};
```

Comment: Thank you this got me past my initial hurdle so the print statements are working correctly. I've noticed that any generic interfaces I add to Box<T> I have to duplicate in the std::pair specialization. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Looking through some related questions, template specialization with this inheritance property seems possible. Just not too sure what is wrong with my example.